# How to set AFFINITY with CALL in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, jboss, affinity

Im using the command `start /AFFINITY 3 standalone.bat` to start jboss 7.1.1 from a command line.

Now I want to create a windows service to start jboss with AFFINITY , so what is the equivalent of this command using CALL from another batch file (service.bat)?

I tried: `Call /AFFINITY 3 standalone.bat`

But didn't work.

Im using the service.bat described here (http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/run-jboss-as-service-howto)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
start "" /WAIT /AFFINITY 3 /B  cmd /c "standalone.bat"
```

?

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but when i added this command to my service , the service can't start , i get an error :


'some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs'


Im using the service.bat described here (http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/run-jboss-as-service-howto)

Comment: @user986586, does it happen without this `start` command? If yes then that's a separate issue for a new question.

Comment: No , it's happened just when i added   start  command by replacing this line :

`call standalone.bat --server-config=standalone.xml < .r.lock >> %JBOSS_HOME%\standalone\log\standalone.log 2>&1`


with :


`start "" /WAIT /AFFINITY 3 /B  cmd /c "standalone.bat" < .r.lock >> %JBOSS_HOME%\standalone\log\standalone.log 2>&1`

Comment: try to put all  the things related to called command in quotes:

Comment: `"standalone.bat < .r.lock >> %JBOSS_HOME%\standalone\log\standalone.log 2>&1"`

Comment: @npocmaka  Still having the same error , i think the problem is the `start` command

Comment: Well, `/AFFINITY` is a switch of `start` command only. There is no way to use `/AFFINITY` without `start`...